# How to preserve HTML entities in JS string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, html-entities

I have text content in an element that uses HTML entities for quotes. I need to get this content and insert it into a data attribute on another element, which of course requires the quotes to remain escaped. But no matter what I do, JS keeps converting the entities to characters. How can I prevent this?

```js
let lmnt = document.getElementById('lmnt');

console.log(lmnt.textContent);
console.log(lmnt.innerHTML);
console.log(lmnt.innerText);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="lmnt">Robert &quot;Bob&quot; Robertson</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you setting the data attribute? `element.dataset['somename'] = lmnt.textContent` should work fine.

Comment: @Ivar I'm creating new elements using template literals appended via jQuery like `.append($.parseHTML(item));`

Comment: I do not think this is possible. The browser converts them, effectively losing `&quot;`. You would have to write some function with regex to capture what got converted and revert them back to their HTML entity.

Comment: @cela thank you; I'll do that.